# Issue with disabling cursor on textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application, i have a calendar where i should not allow user to type date. And also tab out should work on that textbox. The below code enables cursor in textbox.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pickup_Schedule_Date, new { @class = "dpicker", @placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy", @id = "Pickupdate",@style = "cursor:pointer;" })
```

Comment: Are you want to disable writing on textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pickup_Schedule_Date, new { @class = "dpicker", @placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy", @id = "Pickupdate",@style = "cursor:pointer;" disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })`